# Shape class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to make a little shape helper object to help me with the drawing of shapes on html 5 canvas. So far I have;

```
var Shape = function (config) {

    this.initialize(config);
};

var proto = Shape.prototype;

proto.initialize = function (config) {

    this.x = config.x || 0;
    this.y = config.y || 0;
    this.width = config.width || 0;
    this.height = config.height || 0;
    this.color = config.color || false;
};

/*
    Circle
*/

var Circle = function (config) {

    this.initialize(config);
};

proto = Circle.prototype;

proto = new Shape();
```

But it does not seem to work! When I call to create a new circle like so;

```
var s1 = new Circle({x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10, color: "red"});
```

How can I create a base class `Shape` that will help set up other shapes and assign some common properties that shapes shall have such as, `Circle`, `Rect` ect?

I am trying to learn javascript so if the code is way off please explain why and how I can better it,

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proto = new Shape();`

This assigns the `proto` variable to refer to a new `Shape` instance.
It does not affect `Circle.prototype`, which that variable happened to previously refer to.

---

Note that you're running the `Shape()` constructor to initialize the Circle prototype, which is probably not a good idea.
Instead, you can write

```
Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
```

This code will create a new object that inherits `Shape.prototype`, without running its constructor.

Comment: What are the possible issues with `Circle.prototype = new Shape()`? I often see this kind of code, mainly when browsers that do not implement ES5 are concerned.

Comment: @user2251919 Objects are passed by reference. You're storing a reference to the `Circle.prototype` object in the `proto` variable. Assigning a new object to `proto` will not affect `Circle.prototype`, but rather will just assign a new reference to the `proto` variable. SLaks explains it in the first section of the answer.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté#1: If the `Shape()` constructor has side-effects, or creates things like arrays, it can get messed up, since you're effectively running the constructor twice for each instance (once in the prototype)

Answer (score 0):

change this lines:

```
proto = Circle.prototype;

proto = new Shape();
```

with:

```
Circle.prototype = new Shape();
```